# Minimization in Maple

Tags: function, optimization, maple, minimization

I am trying to minimize a function of 14 variables in maple. I have tried using the built-in NLPSolve() and Minimize() functions out of the Optimization package and they are taking too long (I let them run for over 3 hr with nothing to show for it).

Any suggestions on how I could get around this? I would like to write my own minimization code, but I don't know how to get started. Any tips on that? Or, any example codes I could work off of?

Comment: It's difficult to speculate on the source of your problems without seeing the function you describe. You might try and post this question along with your associated Maple worksheet to the Maple user forum at: http://www.mapleprimes.com/